# Filedepot - Where is the file management interface?

Tags: 7

I have installed the module and additional libraries as required in the README but I don't see where the file management interface is. Can someone give me the link or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `hook_menu()` implementations for Drupal 6 and 7 these two paths stick out:

- Filedepot ( http://mysite.com/filedepot )
- Filedepot Settings ( http://mysite.com/admin/settings/filedepot )

The rest of the paths defined are variations on the above, or AJAX callbacks, so I think one of those is the path you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is correct, but I have still an error: `jQuery.blockUI is not a function` and the library is installed.

Comment: It looks like it's a [known bug](http://drupal.org/node/1470858) :/